# Windows 10 - Totally and Completely Stop my Built-in IIS Server

Tags: windows-10, iis, windows-services

On my windows 10 machine, any time I try to access HTTP port 80, it is in use and cannot be bound to. I understand this is being used by the IIS that comes with Windows 10. However, I don't have a single web server configured. This is what my IIS Manager looks like:
[image: Windows 10 IIS Manager]

Despite not having any sites at all, when I navigate to http://localhost, I see:
[image: Windows 10 IIS locahost not found]

In my Windows Services, there is no WAS or W3SVC.

In my experience, this means there is some process somewhere bound to this port that I can probably terminate, kill, and completely stop totally.

How do I do this? I'd like other things that are not this to bind to port 80.

Comment: I assume if you look at the `System` process in Process Explorer (TCP/IP tab of the process properties) it is listening on port 80.  If you run `net stop http` it stops listening.

Comment: I am cautious of this because when I run `net stop http`, I am told that two services are dependent on them; namely `SSDP Discovery` and `Print Spooler`. Though I don't know much about the former, I would hate to shut off the latter for fear that I will no longer be able to print. I guess if there is no other way...

Comment: If you are not using IIS, just uninstall it in "Turn Windows features on or off". This won't break anything.

Comment: @harrymc - I did just this, and after turning off "Internet Information Services" (and restarting, which is required) there is still a service listening on port 80 generating the page above. This is bizarre.

Comment: Please run in cmd the command `netsh http show iplisten`. See also if `netsh http show urlacl` shows anything starting with `http://+:80`.